# Perform Task at a given interval using TTask - Sleep alternative

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to perform a task every x seconds and I can accomplish that goal using the code below:

```
var task: ITask;
begin

  task := TTask.Create(
    procedure()

    begin

      //infinite loop
      while 1 = 1 do
      begin

        //time interval
        sleep(15000);


        //do something every x seconds

      end;

    end);

  task.Start;
```

However, when using sleep (x) I cannot finish the task at any time, for example, when I close the form (I'm using VCL).

What would be an alternative to perform a task infinitely at a fixed interval, but with the possibility of interrupting the task without waiting for sleep to finish? I saw an article about using TEvent, however I didn't quite understand how it works.

Comment: See [How do you detect that a TEvent has been set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13993041/576719) Instead of calling `Sleep()`, just call the event `WaitFor(15000)` method. If the event is signalled, break the task, otherwise just do the loop work task.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Sleep, use a waitable object, such as TEvent, and signal it when you want to end the task. Wait on the object for X seconds. If signaled, exit. If timed out, do the task. Repeat in a loop